# Android Play Game Services publishing vs testing problems

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I am currently creating an android game using the Play Game Services for leader boards and achievements. I am currently testing the features under my account because I can clear the leader board when needed. However, I wanted to release an alpha test of my app. When I try to publish my game so my testers have access to it, it says I have to publish the Game Services first or they won't work. But, if I publish the game services can I still use testing accounts and change things? Or will it be final?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to "release" [edited] your game in order for testers to try out your game. One reason you may get the "I have to publish the Game Services first..." is because you most likely did not complete the Game Services and API setup between Google Play Developer Console and the app itself.

See steps:

https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/enabling#a_create_a_linked_application

Or, less likely, it could be that you still need to upload the APK:

Upload an Alpha or Beta APK, wait a few hours for it to become active in the system, and then add your tester group. This is a good place to start as of the date of my post:

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213

Some details from the link above:

**Set up alpha/beta tests**

Using the Google Play Developer Console, you can choose groups of users to beta test different versions of your app.

**Testing basics**

With the alpha/beta testing tools available in your Developer account, you can test different versions of your app.

- You don't need a production APK to publish an alpha/beta app.
- Users need a Google Account (@gmail.com) or a Google Apps account to join a test.
- If you're testing an existing app that you've published before, only users in your test group will receive an update for your alpha/beta version. If you're testing a new app that you haven't published before, only users in your test group can find and download your app.
- After publishing an alpha/beta APK for the first time, it may take a few hours for your test link to be available to testers. If you publish additional changes, they may take several hours to be available for testers.
- If you make any changes to your app's Pricing & Distribution page, including setting your app price to Paid or Free, it affects your production, alpha, beta, and any future versions of your app.

Tip: When you're starting a new alpha/beta test, it's a good idea to start with a small group of alpha testers, then expand your test to a larger beta test group.

Definitely make sure to see more at the provided link: 
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213